# Change Speed Of One Team In Counter-Strike: Global Offensive

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

I have my own dedicated server, my friends and I had an idea to make the terrorists fast and the counter terrorists had to chase them, is there anyway to set this up. I am willing to use plugins or anything to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I found this plugin while looking around, and I now know how to do this!
https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=1913554